# Do any jurisdictions allow you to "buy out" your property tax?

Tags: taxes, property

Many jurisdictions around the world have a property tax that is paid yearly on real estate.  Do any jurisdictions have a system where all future property taxes for a property can be bought out for a fee?  The buy out would act as a perpetual annuity funding future property taxes.

Comment: How would that handle your property tax4s increasing in the future?

Comment: All future taxes, like... *forever?* How would you price it?

Comment: That's 2 downvotes for apparently asking for a simple bit of information:  does anyone do this?  Let's not confuse whether it's a good, efficient, or equitable idea - I don't think so either - with simply asking about whether it's done or not.  Note that there's no particular amount of verbiage pushing its advantages on this Q either.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short Answer

> Do any jurisdictions have a system where all future property taxes for
> a property can be bought out for a fee?

No.

#### Long Answer

**Similar Cases**

There are many circumstances that are similar to the one proposed by the question, but not identical.

*Transfers To Property Tax Exempt Entities*

Most property tax systems recognize that some taxpayers, such as governmental entities, churches, and sometimes all non-profit entities, are exempt from property taxation.

A transfer of property to a property tax exempt entity effectively eliminates all future property tax obligations associates with that parcel of real estate until the property is transferred to a person or entity that is not exempt from property taxes.

Some property tax exempt entities (such as state universities) make payments to local governments in lieu of property taxes to provide local services, either voluntarily because they need the local services to exist, or in a manner provided by law.

But none of these examples are true "buy-outs" of property tax obligations since the government imposing the property taxes doesn't get any of the proceeds of the purchase price paid by the property tax exempt entity to the seller of the property.

*Buy-Outs Of Leases From The Government*

Something comparable exists in situations where the government leases land to people on very long term leases (most notably in China which does not have property taxes, but also in other places for a variety of reasons - the house in Oxford, Ohio that I grew up in was on a long term lease that was bought out and converted to fee simple absolute ownership about 30 or 40 years into the 99 year lease from the government).

Many jurisdictions allow people who lease a residence from the government to buy out their lease so that they own the residence free in clear using the difference between the legally determined value of the residence at either the start of the lease or the present, with credit given for rent paid by the tenant of the government - essentially including a rent to own option in residential leases from the government.

In some respects, the very existence of private property is a form of lease buy-out.

In the United States, for example, all land that was not owned by another specific property owner at the time it became a part of the United States is owned by the federal government.

When land or other natural resources (e.g. oil and gas) are owned by the government and a private party wants to use them, that private party has to lease the land from the federal government (usually through the Bureau of Land Management and usually for either grazing or for oil and gas extraction).

But, at various times, the federal government has allowed private persons to gain ownership of federal government real property rights in a document called a "patent", often at nominal prices, especially in the 1800s, under the various Homestead Acts (all of which have now expired, with the last ones that had been in force in Alaska), under land grants to states for education, under land grants to railroads, and under laws related to mining claims on federal lands. These were essentially spending programs intended to subsidize development of these lands in various ways.

*Property Taxes Pledged To Pay Municipal Bonds Until Paid In Full*

Likewise, some property taxes are imposed to pay a specific municipal bond obligation, and in a special district government, the number of property tax payers may be just one or a very small number and that can be paid off by paying off the bond for whose payment the property tax is authorized.

*Property Tax-Like Development Fees*

One can also sometimes buy out property tax-like impositions that are used to fund development costs for a parcel of land in a special improvement district, where again, the total duration and aggregate amount to be collected from the tax over its duration are established in advance.

*Property Tax Deferral*

Many jurisdictions allow some homeowner's to defer paying property taxes until the sale of their property or their death, although details vary greatly from program to program. Typically:

> Property tax deferrals allow elderly and disabled homeowners to defer
> payment until the sale of the property or the death of the taxpayer.
> Twenty-seven states and the District of Columbia allowed such
> deferrals in 2020, but they are not widely used.

([Source](https://www.urban.org/policy-centers/cross-center-initiatives/state-and-local-finance-initiative/projects/state-and-local-backgrounders/property-taxes))

**No Jurisdictions Have This Option**

But, I am not aware of anyplace where an annual payment to the government that is framed as a genuine tax to pay the general obligations of a government which has many property owners in its jurisdiction can be bought out in this fashion.

One of the reasons this is not done is that it presented multiple complications.

*Complications Involved In Calculating A Buy-Out*

Among other things, the proper buyout amount is challenging to compute in a credible fashion to due inflation, changing property values, and changing property tax rates over time.

*Complications Since Many Governments Impose Them*

Also, in most jurisdictions with property taxes in the United States, at least, there are multiple governments that all impose property taxes and a deal would have to be reached with all of them.

> Property taxes are a very small source of revenue for states because
> states typically tax personal property but not real property. (Census
> does not provide a separate count for each type of property tax.)
> State governments collected $19 billion from property taxes in 2020,
> or 1 percent of state general revenue. In contrast, property taxes are
> one of the largest sources of revenue for local governments. Local
> governments collected $581 billion in property taxes in 2020, or 30
> percent of local general revenue.
>
> School districts, counties, municipalities, and townships all collect
> property tax revenue, and it typically accounts for a significant
> share of general revenues in those jurisdictions. Property tax revenue
> is a smaller share of special district general revenue because these
> specific-purpose jurisdictions, such as water and sewer authorities,
> typically get most of their revenue from taxes related to those
> services. (Census only publishes revenue totals for these levels of
> government for years ending in 2 and 7.)

[image]

([Source](https://www.urban.org/policy-centers/cross-center-initiatives/state-and-local-finance-initiative/projects/state-and-local-backgrounders/property-taxes) for quoted material and image)

*Eminent Domain Power Complications*

Another complication of a permanent buy-out of property taxes on a parcel of real property is how  the eminent domain power of governments to seize private property for a public purpose in exchange for a judicially determined fair market value of the property impacts and interacts with such a deal.

**Private Options To Achieve Similar Results**

It would, in contrast, be easy to set aside money to be held in trust in an investment with a fixed income stream sufficient to service the debt in perpetuity with reasonable assumptions. This does still leave the property owner with the risk that there will be property tax liabilities that have to be paid out of pocket in the future.

This is what is done in real life to close out bond obligations in the case of bonds for which pre-payment is not permitted.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why they "are not widely used"? Are there complicated qualification requirements?

Comment: @Fizz I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

##### Frame challenge:  why would this be considered a good idea?

(I understand the *emotional* appeal.  The *economics* don't make much sense to me though, especially the *risks* aspects).

As commented, how about tax increases?  Fair enough, if it's just the municipality increasing taxes, or the area increasing in value:  that's what the buy out purchaser is hoping to avoid, and paying for.  Very hard to price, but OK, let's go with the question.

But what if someone buys a fixer upper and then increases its value massively by renovations?  How do you price that?

Also, how would this work with transfers of ownership, via sales or inheritance?

If it doesn't carry over, a deal would "lock in" the current owner as they would take a net loss selling it.

If it does, that means the municipality foregoes all revenue in perpetuity, which would by definition mean a huge initial outlay to "pay via interest".  **Something the homeowner could do on their own, considering they have all that money available**.  And remain untethered should they want to move.  Granted, that does not cover the risks of the municipality raising its taxes, but a municipality's actuaries would presumably price the premium for opting out of ever raising prices quite aggressively.  Possibly more aggressively than local voters' tolerance for actual property tax increases would warrant.

In day to day commercial activities, "good for life" memberships seem mostly limited to cases where there is limited variable costs associated with providing a service to each additional customer. Is that the case with a municipality serving a property? And where the initial outlay is relatively trivial to the customer, say golf memberships for the very wealthy. This is not the case with properties as residential buyers will mostly "buy up" to have a house representing a significant fraction of their wealth, meaning that property tax buyoff would be huge.

How assured would one be that a municipality would do well out of big chunks of one-off windfall $$$?  The internet is not short of stories about cities getting themselves into financial trouble by mismanaging capital investments, engaging in risky commercial ventures, or embezzlement.  Add to this the risk of initially under-pricing the buy out to "sell it" to the public (the current mayor won't mind, it'll be their successor dealing with it).

This practice seems like it would enhance those risks, just like lottery wins don't always work out.  *And that's also a risk for the buy out customer, if the municipality goes bankrupt.*

p.s. Anecdotally, caveat emptor:  a fancy hot yoga place nearby had, IIRC, 1K $CAD per year plans.  Or a "for life" membership @ $11K.  Within 5 years of me first seeing that sign they were gone.  They might have moved.  Or not - I never saw them again anywhere in the area.

p.p.s JonathanReez's comment - *stop paying taxes until you die, at which point they'll be taken out of your estate* - has little of my noted downsides, *if applied to older seniors, with limited outstanding mortgages*.  It would reduce the negative press coming from all the sad stories covering the impact of property taxes on the very old.

(How would an 85 year old who wants to leave town to be with their grandchildren pay say 10 years of accumulated backlog though?  Probably through proceeds of a sale - which is why you'd want to limit it to people with low mortgages)

Overall I feel SE Economics would do a better job of pointing out the drawbacks, they have the specialized terminology and tools to assess this kind of proposal.  My gut feel however is that it makes little sense.